# Wordpress - old favicon shows up in Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, favicon

I have a wordpress website and when I check the favicons added in the header its all the new favicons. It was working well in Chrome, suddenly after clearing the cache old favicon starts showing up in chrome. This is not the case in Firefox and IE. The call in the network points to the old Favicon, I don't know how. Under the site identify the new favicon is only set. This issue started coming up when I cleared the page cache using 'Purge page speed cache'.

Comment: Delete old favicon from directory wp-content upload or Admin media option & upload new favicon.

Comment: Only the new logo is present in the wp-content upload. It was uploaded few months back and now all of a sudden the old one started to appear.

Comment: Can you please check site view source code in browser and open favicon in new tab for preview image and reload it.